# código para retornar divisores e comparar os comuns

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparação, divisão

Estou tentando criar um código que me retorne os divisores comuns entre 2 variáveis que recebem números inteiros. E depois mostre os divisores comuns.

Para me retornar os divisores estou usando esse código para teste:

```
import numpy as np

def divisores(num):

n = np.arange(1,num)

d = num % n

zeros = d == 0

print (n[zeros])

divisores(30)
```

Porém eu preciso que essa função me retorne os divisores de 2 valores e não apenas um. Além de comparar os divisores comuns entre eles, pois não consegui pensar em uma forma de fazer.

Answer (score 4):

Podemos deixar a solução um pouco mais genérica. Vamos imaginar que podemos definir uma quantidade não limitada de valores para determinar os divisores comuns entre eles. Podemos fazer isso através da função:

```
def divisores(*numeros):
    ...
```

Assim, se desejarmos os divisores comuns de 5 e 10, podemos chamar `divisores(5, 10)`, e se desejarmos os divisores de 42, 100 e 999, basta chamarmos `divisores(42, 100, 999)`. Se considerarmos, por exemplo, a entrada 42, 100 e 999, é fácil perceber que todos os divisores comuns dos três números será divisor de cada número individualmente, o que implica que todos os divisores deverão ser menor ou igual ao menor dos valores da entrada, pois não tem como um valor maior que 42 ser divisor de 42. Assim, sabemos que basta percorrer todos os valores entre 1 e o menor valor da entrada:

```
def divisores(*numeros):
    menor = min(numeros)
    for i in range(1, menor+1):
        ...
```

E para definir se `i` é divisor de todos os números da entrada, podemos utilizar a função `all` e verificar se o resto de divisão de todos os números de entrada por `i` é 0.

```
def divisores(*numeros):
    menor = min(numeros)
    for i in range(1, menor+1):
        if all(numero % i == 0 for numero in numeros):
            yield i
```

Com o `yield` retornamos um gerador que itera sobre os divisores de todos os números de entrada.

```
print('Divisores de 5 e 10:', list(divisores(5, 10)))  # [1, 5]
print('Divisores de 42, 100 e 999:', list(divisores(42, 100, 999)))  # [1]
print('Divisores de 14, 38 e 74:', list(divisores(14, 38, 74)))  # [1, 2]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FarawayOblongRepository) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/mr5Ap7)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Aproveitando a função que tem para calcular os divisores, fica-lhe a faltar pouco para concluir o problema. De forma a conseguir re-utilizar a função que tem a melhor opção é transformar o `print` num `return`:

```
def divisores(num):
    n = np.arange(1,num)
    d = num % n
    zeros = d == 0
    return n[zeros]
```

Na verdade é sempre melhor fazer isso pois faz com que a função possa ser utilizada em qualquer lugar sem ter que obrigatoriamente forçar uma escrita.

Agora basta construir uma função que receba dois números, chame o `divisores` para cada um desses números e obtenha os números comuns de cada conjunto. Tem muitas formas de obter os números comuns de cada conjunto e eu irei optar pela interseção de `set`:

```
def divisores_comuns(num1, num2):
    divs1 = set(divisores(num1)) # obtendo os divisores e transformando em set
    divs2 = set(divisores(num2)) # obtendo os divisores e transformando em set
    return divs1 & divs2 # & é a intereseção de dois sets
```

[Veja este código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/YDz42h)

Comment: Bem, eu utilizaria essa. A abordagem é mais objetiva e mais polida.

Answer (score 0):

Ana,

Para receber dois valores, deve-se ou considerar N como uma lista de inteiros, ou receber dois argumentos na assinatura da função, como:

`def divisores(num1, num2):`

Apesar do seu procedimento funcionar, repare o seguinte:

1. Você testa a divisão de todos os números entre 0 - número recebido, mesmo que a menor divisão possível (2), aconteça no num/2;
2. Você testa, novamente, toda array do numpy se o restante da divisão é 0;

Apesar de não ser um algoritmo muito charmoso, uma maneira que realizas menos iterações é a seguinte:

```
div_1 = set() #Cria um set vazio
for i in range(1, int(num1/2+1)): #itera de 1 até metade do valor numérico
    if num1%i == 0: #testa se mod é zero.
        div_1.add(i) #anexa o valor de i ao set de divisores do primeiro numero
```

Vale lembrar, que essa função, assim como seu código, não retorna o próprio valor como um possível divisor (no caso, quando você insere 30, os valores obtidos serão:{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15} ) (30 excluso). Além disso, é possível considerar o uso do objeto "set" ao invés de listas, visto que os números não devem repetir.

No caso, se a função final fosse apenas achar a intersecção dos valores comuns de divisão, você poderia incluir tudo no mesmo loop, como não é, uma abordagem simplista é rodar outra iteração no para identificar os mesmos divisores do outro número (num2).

Para a intersecção, você poderia realizar o seguinte:

```
lista_divisores_comuns = div_1.intersection(div_2)
```

O código final ficaria como:

```
def divisores(num1, num2):    
    div_1 = set()
    div_2 = set()
    for i in range(1, int(num1/2+1)):
        if num1%i == 0:
            div_1.add(i)

    for i in range(1, int(num2/2+1)):
        if num2%i == 0:
            div_2.add(i)


    lista_divisores_comuns = div_1.intersection(div_2)

    return div_1, div_2, lista_divisores_comuns
```